# Properties defined outside of class declaration in C++

Tags: c++-cli

Is it possible to declare a variable outside of a class?

For example,

```
// a.h
ref class A
{
public:
    property String^ P;
private:
    String ^p;
};

// a.cpp
/* Define property here */
```

Comment: No, you do this with a global variable, not a property. When defined outside of a class, it is not a property of anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can at least do this, I just tested:

```
// a.h
ref class A
{
public:
    property String^ P { String^ get(); void set(String^); }
private:
    String ^p;
};
```

Which you define thusly:

```
// a.cpp
String^ A::P::get() { return p; }
void A::P::set(String^ value) { p = value; }
```

It compiles.

---

In short, you can't just declare a property without declaring what its accessors are, so the compiler can know whether the property can be read, written, overridden, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. I should have tried that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

All variables should ideally be defined within the class. Static member needs to be initialized outside class declaration, and non-static members to be initialized through constructor. Global data, however, can be declared and initilalized outside the class (no relation with the class)

```
// a.h
extern int ga;
class A
{
   int m_a;
   static int s_a;
public:
    A(int aa) : m_a(aa){
      // constructor
    }
};

// a.cpp
int ga = 4; // global data initialization
int A::s_a = 0; // class static data initialization
```

Comment: Okay, so properties must be define inside the class definition? It makes the class definition a lot longer.